# Same program faster on Linux than Windows -- why?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, gcc, benchmarking

**The solution** to this was found in the question [Executable runs faster on Wine than Windows -- why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081919/executable-runs-faster-on-wine-than-windows-why)  Glibc's `floor()` is probably implemented in terms of system libraries.

---

I have a very small C++ program (~100 lines) for a physics simulation.  I have compiled it with gcc 4.6.1 on both Ubuntu Oneiric and Windows XP on the same computer.  I used precisely the same command line options (same makefile).

Strangely, on Ubuntu, the program finishes *much* faster than on Windows (~7.5 s vs 13.5 s).  At this point I thought it's a compiler difference (despite using the same version).

But even more strangely, if I run the Windows executable under wine, it's still faster than on Windows (I get 11 s "real" and 7.7 s "user" time -- and this includes wine startup.)

I'm confused.  Surely if the same code is run on the same CPU, there shouldn't be a difference in the timing.

**What can be the reason for this?**  What could I be doing wrong?

The program does minimal I/O (outputs a single line), and only uses a fixed-length `vector` from the STL (i.e. no system libraries should be involved).  On Ubuntu I used the default gcc and on Windows the [Nuwen distribution](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html).  I verified that the CPU usage is close to zero when doing the benchmarking (I closed most programs). On Linux I used `time` for timing.  On Windows I used `timethis.exe`.

**UPDATE**

I did some more precise timings, comparing the running time for different inputs (run-time must be proportional to the input) of the gcc and msvc-compiled programs on Windows XP, Wine and Linux.  All numbers are in seconds and are the minimum of at least 3 runs.

On Windows I used [timethis.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=3087) (wall time), on Linux and Wine I used time (CPU time).  (timethis.exe is broken on Wine)  I made sure no other programs were using the CPU and disabled the virus scanner.

The command line options to gcc were `-march=pentium-m -Wall -O3 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti` (i.e. exceptions were disabled).

[image: Timings]

**What we see from this data:**

1. the difference is not due to process startup time, as run-times are proportional to the input
2. The difference between running on Wine and Windows exists only for the gcc-compiled program, not the msvc-compiled one: it can't be casued by other programs hogging the CPU on Windows or timethis.exe being broken.

Comment: How much memory is this thing using? Have you tried running it under a profiler?

Comment: It that like saying if 2 different cars (a truck and a small sports car) use the same engine they should accelerate at the same rate?

Comment: Could it be that on Windows the startup time is larger? If you make the program run longer, how does that affect the time difference between Windows and Linux?

Comment: @bdonlan It is using less than 1 MB according to Process Explorer.

Comment: @celtschk I will check that.  I can't reply fast because I need to reboot again to test on Linux.

Comment: You should also test MSVC on Windows, it's likely to be faster than GCC being the native compiler (in some cases, MSVC-built under Win is even faster than GCC under nix). If you can get your hands on it, try ICC as well.

Comment: @peachykeen I did try the compiler from VC++ Express 2010, which gives me around 11.5 s.  I should try the MSVC compiled executable on Wine too.

Comment: Another thought: Did you measure processor time or wall time? If the latter, it might just be more background processes running on Windows and taking away processor cycles (for example some antivirus program).

Comment: Do you have any optimizations enabled, in any of the compilers?

Comment: @celtschk Please see my update to the post, it will answer your questions.

Answer (score 5):

You'd be surprised what system libraries are involved. Just do ldd on your app, and see which are used (ok, not that much, but certainly glibc).

In order to completely trust your findings about *execution speed*, you would need to run your app a couple of times sequentially and take the mean execution time. It might be that the OS loader is just slower (although 4s is a long loading time).

Other very possible reasons are:

1. Different malloc implementation
2. Exception handling, if used to the extreme might cause slowdown (Windows GCC, MinGW, might not be the optimal exception handling star of the show)
3. OS-dependent initialization: stuff that needs to be done at program startup on Windows, but not on Linux.

Most of these are easily benchmarkable ;-)

---

An update to your update: the only thing you can now do is profile. Stop guessing, and let a profiler tell you where time is being spent. Use gprof and the Visual Studio built-in profiler and compare time spent in different functions.

Comment: I ran it many times, to make sure the timing is correct (I studied physics, so I learned the lesson during lab classes).  OK, so first I'll increase the single-run time to above a minute, I'll disable exceptions (I'm not using them), will use a C-style array in place of `std::vector` to get rid of all malloc/new, then I'll try again.  It'll take a while as I need to reboot too.

Comment: Please see my edit to the question.  I ruled out points 2. and 3.  Point 1. is still a possibility, but from what I understand, my program shouldn't allocate memory on the heap, except at startup when an `std::vector` is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Do benchmarking in code. Also try to compile with visual studio. On windows if you have some application like Yahoo Messenger, that are installing hooks, they can very easy slow down your application loading times.

On windows you have: QueryPerformanceCounter
On Linux: clock_gettime

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the difference is system related.

You might use `strace` to understand what system calls are done, eg

```
strace -o /tmp/yourprog.tr yourprog
```

and then look into `/tmp/yourprog.tr`

(If an equivalent of `strace` existed on Windows, try to use it)

Perhaps your program is allocating memory (using `mmap` system call), and perhaps the memory related system calls are faster on Linux (or even on Wine) than on Windows? Or some other syscalls give faster functionality on Linux that on Windows.

NB. I know nothing about Windows, since I'm using Unix systems since 1986 and Linux since 1993.

Comment: I'll try that.  Regarding your edit to the title, there's a difference for the same executable too, run on either Windows or Wine (not just when the source is compiled on different systems). Which is really weird to me.

Comment: When you use Wine, you are indirectly using the Linux kernel. So it is not so weird (both with Wine and under Linux, you are using the same kernel).