# check the performance of an exe through code

Tags: c++, windows, performance

I want to check the performance of an application (whose exe i have, no source code) by running it multiple times and possibly compare the results, dint find much on the internet regarding this topic,

Since i have to do it with multiple input times, i thought doing it through code(no bar on the language used) can make things easier, as i may have to repeat them many times,
can anyone help me start off???

Note: by Performance i mean the memory usage, cpu and possibly the time taken to do it!

(I'm currently using perfmon on windows by using necessary counters to check these parameters and manually noting it down)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the perform im using to manually note down in an automated way,
that is, i used the performance counter class available in dot net and obtained samples of the particular application at regular intervals and generated a graph with those values..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It strongly **depends upon your operating system**. On *Linux*, you could use the [time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) utility. And [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) might help you understanding the system calls that are used.

I have no idea of the equivalent on Windows systems.

Comment: i want it for windows, sorry for not mentioning that, im currently using perfmon (inbuilt on windows) to do it manually,

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could create a bash/batch script to call your program as many times as you need and with different inputs.

You could then have your script create a CSV file that contains the time it took to execute your program (start date and end date for example). CSV files are usually compatible with most spreadsheet programs like Excel, so I think that can make it easier for you to process your data, like creating means and standard deviations.

I don't have much to say regarding the memory and CPU usage, but if you are in Windows it wouldn't hurt to take a look at the Process Explorer and the Process Monitor (you can find them in [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533) page). I think that they might help you in your task.

Finally if you are in Linux I think that you might be able to use grep with the top command to gather some statistics.

Regards,

Felipe

Comment: im using windows, and that is an exe i have, and u r right.. process explorer has that capability, but as i mentioned with these tools i have to do it manually, but i want to automate it :) so im looking for an alternate approach :)

Comment: Well, I think that this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) might be useful then. Perhaps the PSInfo or the PSList will do the trick for you... They are command line programs so you can parse their results and create something of an automatic testing script.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exact results, Rational Purify (on Windows), or valgrind (on Linux) are the best tools; these run your application in a virtual machine that can be instructed to do exact cycle counting.

Answer (score 1):

In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071851/same-program-faster-on-linux-than-windows-why)  an utility named [timethis.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=3087) was mentioned for measuring time under Windows. Maybe it is useful for your purposes.